# Execute stored procedure with parameters postgresql

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, stored-functions

My Npgsql version 3.2.5 - Postgresql 9.6

I get this error with `CommandType.StoredProcedure` (but `CommandType.Text` works):

> Npgsql.PostgresException: '42883: function customer_select(pEmail => text, Password => text) does not exist'

```
string sql3 = @"customer_select";

NpgsqlConnection pgcon = new NpgsqlConnection(pgconnectionstring);
pgcon.Open();
NpgsqlCommand pgcom = new NpgsqlCommand(sql3, pgcon);
pgcom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
pgcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(":pEmail", "myemail@hotmail.com");
pgcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(":pPassword", "eikaylie78");
NpgsqlDataReader pgreader = pgcom.ExecuteReader();

while (pgreader.Read()) {
    string name = pgreader.GetString(1);
    string surname = pgreader.GetString(2);
}
```

This is the function in the database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.customer_select(
    pemail character varying, ppassword character varying)
RETURNS SETOF "CustomerTest"
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100.0
AS $function$                                   
BEGIN 
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT "CustomerTestId", "FirstName", "LastName", "Email", "Password"
        FROM public."CustomerTest"
        WHERE "Email" = pEmail AND "Password" = pPassword;
END; 
$function$;
ALTER FUNCTION public.customer_select(character varying, character varying)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Provide detailed error message

Comment: Full message text : function customer_select(pEmail => text, pPassword => text) does not exist

Npgsql.PostgresException occurred
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=42883: function customer_select(pEmail => text, pPassword => text) does not exist
  Source=Npgsql
  StackTrace:
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<DoReadMessage>d__148.MoveNext()
   at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Npgsql does support named parameters, but your parameters' case doesn't match your functions', try `pemail` instead of `pEmail` and `ppassword` instead of `pPassword`.

Note that there's no particular advantage to using `CommandType.StoredProcedure` over `CommandType.Text` with Npgsql - both end up doing the same thing. `CommandType.StoredProcedure` is mainly to ease porting code from SqlServer etc.

Comment: I fixed the parameter names (pEmail to pemail) and when i used "CommandType.StoredProcedure"  it works ! thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to the [issue](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/305) the *NPS SQL* doesn't support named parameters because PostgreSQL doesn't. But you can try following:

```
string sql3 = @"select * from customer_select(:pEmail, :pPassword)";    
NpgsqlConnection pgcon = new NpgsqlConnection(pgconnectionstring);
pgcon.Open();
NpgsqlCommand pgcom = new NpgsqlCommand(sql3, pgcon);
pgcom.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
pgcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("pEmail", "myemail@hotmail.com");
pgcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("pPassword", "eikaylie78");
NpgsqlDataReader pgreader = pgcom.ExecuteReader();

while (pgreader.Read()) {
    string name = pgreader.GetString(1);
    string surname = pgreader.GetString(2);
}
```

According to this [issue](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1197)

Comment: pgcom.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
it works with this code